# Hadoop installation trouble

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am installing hadoop on my windows PC. I was able to start yarn and dfs. I ran this command `hadoop fs -mkdir /in`

It displays the following error:

`-mkdir: java.net.UnknownHostException: master`

I am newbie Please explain me what has to be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates the host `master` cannot be resolved to an IP address. You probably need to add a mapping for it in your `hosts` file so it can be resolved.

Comment: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host right ? can you tell what address i should give for master?

Comment: That's the correct file. It would be the IP address of the machine running the master i would think.

Comment: i Changed the master ip.I get this error                                                                   mkdir: Call From 8K-CHN-D005/192.168.0.4 to master:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection
fused: no further information; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused.                               What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you work through the suggestions on that wiki page?

Comment: @ Binary Nerd : how to know which port hadoop is listening?

Comment: You'll find lots of resource on the net about Hadoop port usage, it uses multiple for different things. In you last stacktrace you can see port 9000 mentioned. This question might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22855232/default-namenode-port-of-hdfs-is-50070-but-i-have-come-across-at-some-places-802

Comment: I think i resolved it.Now when i run the mapreduce tasks i get the error                      'exited with non-zero code 9009'                                                                            'Jobs failed as tasks failed'                                                                                               What can be the problem?I am sure the program is alright .Is there any configuration to be done.?