# Unable to read schema from given path: hdfs://...avsc

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, sqoop

I tried to create a hive table by the following steps:

1. load data to hdfs using sqoop (done)
2. sqoop created also a avsc file, which I uploaded to hdfs
3. within hive I want to create a table using the following statement:

Command:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE kontoauszug
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe' 
STORED AS 
INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
LOCATION 'hdfs:///user/tki/KONTOAUSZUG'
TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.url'='hdfs://m1.hdp2/user/tki/KONTOAUSZUG.avsc');
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. 
java.lang.RuntimeException: MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException 
Encountered AvroSerdeException determining schema. 
Returning signal schema to indicate problem: Unable to read schema from given path: hdfs://m1.hdp2/user/tki/KONTOAUSZUG.avsc)
```

Does it mean, KONTOAUSZUG.avsc is not found? I crosschecked it's available.

The content of it is:

```
[hadoop@m1 hive]$ cat KONTOAUSZUG.avsc 
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "KONTOAUSZUG",
  "doc" : "Sqoop import of KONTOAUSZUG",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "FK_PROCESS_ID_INS",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "FK_PROCESS_ID_INS",
    "sqlType" : "2"
  }, {
    "name" : "FK_SOURCE_ID",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "FK_SOURCE_ID",
    "sqlType" : "2"
  }, {
    "name" : "SRC_STM_ID",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "SRC_STM_ID",
    "sqlType" : "2"
  }, {
    "name" : "FK_PROCESS_ID_UPD",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "FK_PROCESS_ID_UPD",
    "sqlType" : "2"
  }, {
    "name" : "BUCHUNGSDATUM",
    "type" : [ "null", "long" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "BUCHUNGSDATUM",
    "sqlType" : "93"
  }, {
    "name" : "BUCHUNGSTEXT",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "BUCHUNGSTEXT",
    "sqlType" : "12"
  }, {
    "name" : "SOLL",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "SOLL",
    "sqlType" : "2"
  }, {
    "name" : "HABEN",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "HABEN",
    "sqlType" : "2"
  }, {
    "name" : "FK_KONTO_ID",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "FK_KONTO_ID",
    "sqlType" : "2"
  }, {
    "name" : "EINGABE_MANUELL_F",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "columnName" : "EINGABE_MANUELL_F",
    "sqlType" : "2"
  } ],
  "tableName" : "KONTOAUSZUG"
}
```

Comment: your `CREATE` statements looks fine to me - are you sure that you are able to list the `.avsc` file? - 
`hadoop fs -ls /user/tki/KONTOAUSZUG.avsc`

Comment: I got this same error when data (hence columns) were missing from tables. The actual error was deeper in the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

In the `CREATE` table statement, you're using three slashes: **hdfs:///** instead of **hdfs://**:

(...)'hdfs:///user/tki/KONTOAUSZUG' TBLPROPERTIES (...)

Besides, if you are getting the schema from the namenode server, I think that you should write the port after the host url.

'avro.schema.url'='hdfs://m1.hdp2:**port**/user/tki/KONTOAUSZUG.avsc'

Check [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AvroSerDe#AvroSerDe-Useavro.schema.url) for the details. And also, [this answer about hdfs ports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22856460/2026277).

Comment: Neither reducing the slashes nor specifying the port solved the issue. I have to add, that I did successfully run the same statement on another (preconfigured cloudera) VM. Any other ideas?

Comment: try using `avro.schema.literal` instead of `url`  - example - http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/cdh/4-x/4-3-0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_26_8.html - OR - this doesnt make sense to the error but you might notice some different behavior:
`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE kontoauszug 
STORED AS AVRO
LOCATION 'hdfs:///user/tki/KONTOAUSZUG'
TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.url'='hdfs://m1.hdp2/user/tki/KONTOAUSZUG.avsc');`

Answer (score 1):

This is an access error. Please check the avsc directory for proper permission and retry
hdfs://m1.hdp2/user/tki/KONTOAUSZUG.avsc