# Hadoop web interface is not working even though the nodes are starting

Tags: hadoop, installation, hadoop3

I'm trying to install Hadoop v3.1.3 in pseudo-distributed mode in my Ubuntu 18.04 environment.

After following the documentation word-by-word, my web interface is still not working i.e. localhost:9870 yields no result. Log files are getting created in `logs` directory but they are empty.

After executing start-all.sh and running `jps`, it outputs:

> 14784 DataNode
> 15689 Jps
> 14619 NameNode
> 15228 ResourceManager
> 15390 NodeManager
> 15007 SecondaryNameNode

localhost:8088 works fine but no other port for the namenodes, secondary nodes etc.

Following are the config files:

etc/hadoop/core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have a look at an answer I wrote to this question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62493064/11550924. That command should show you where the UI is listening.

Comment: I tried the command listed but I'm not getting any output

Answer (score 0):

i think u have installed Hadoop in root user.
please install Hadoop in separate user.

ex:.....

sudo adduser hadoop

then switch to Hadoop user and install Hadoop here.

***i was facing same issue but it has been solve by installing in separate user.

Answer (score 0):

You can open HDFS web console with this

```
localhost:9870
```